# How to fill a Form from data array

Tags: php, arrays, cakephp, fill, formhelper

I have this situation. From the BiograpiesController, after a query, I get this array:

```
    Array (
            [0] => Array (
                    [Biography] => Array (
                            [id] => 7
                            [biography] => AAA
                    )
            )
            [1] => Array (
                    [Biography] => Array (
                            [id] => 9
                            [biography] => BBBBB
                )
        )
    )
```

In the View I want create a Form whit this data. I use:

```
    echo $this->Form->create( 'Biography' ));
    echo $this->Form->input( '0.Biography.biography', array( 'label' => 'A' ));
    echo $this->Form->input( '1.Biography.biography', array( 'label' => 'B' ));
    echo $this->Form->end( );
```

The first field is filled with the correct data, the second is empty. Then I try:

```
    echo $this->Form->input( 'A1', array( 'type' => 'textarea', 'rows' => '10', 'cols' => '40', 'value' => $this->request->data[0]['Biography']['biography'] ));
    echo $this->Form->input( 'B1', array( 'type' => 'textarea', 'rows' => '10', 'cols' => '40', 'value' => $this->request->data[1]['Biography']['biography'] ));
```

The field A1 is filled with the correct data and the second is empty.
Why is this happening?
How can I fill the form with the correct data that I have in the controller?

Thank you very much

Comment: are you sure that $this->request->data in view is exactly how you posted above? Your second solutions should works. Try post a debug($this->request->data)

Comment: Yes, the data are the same. I used to see them: pr($this->request->data).

Comment: I suppose this is edit form of some kind? I suspect there is a problem with your data being displayed in the form because there are two ids, and the form is most likely being populated with data from first array, in your case id 7.

Comment: The main index, 0, 1, are the languages. Each language has a text and an ID. View: echo $Form->input( 'O1', array( 'value' => $this->request->data[0]['Biography']['id'] )); - OK
echo $Form->input( 'O2', array( 'value' => $this->request->data[1]['Biography']['id'] )); - OK
echo $Form->input(...=> $this->request->data[0]['Biography']['biography'] ));  - OK

echo $Form->input( 'A2', array( 'type' => 'text', 'value' => $this->request->data[1] -> ['Biography']['biography'] )); - EMPTY

I want a form with all the data. Thus, in the controller, I can use: $this->Biography->save($this->request->data)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don''t have much knowledge of cakephp but as per the document it should work

```
echo $this->Form->create( 'Biography' ));
echo $this->Form->input( 'Biography.0.biography', array( 'label' => 'A' ));
echo $this->Form->input( 'Biography.1.biography', array( 'label' => 'B' ));
echo $this->Form->end( );
```

Please note the change at 2 and 3rd line

I have referred following link
http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/form.html#field-naming-conventions

Comment: I also tried this solution, but I do not get anything

Comment: Yogesh is correct, this is correct for creating form fields from arrays of model data. If it's not working then you're array may not be in the correct format

Comment: Can you describe the correct model? The array that I get from the Controller should be corrected. The fields that contain the IDs are right (0 and 1), the first textarea field are OK, the second textarea is empty. Why? Thank's